# How to match multi-line text using the right regex capture group?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm trying to read in a CSV and split each row using regex capture groups. The last column of the CSV has newline characters in it and my regex's second capture group seems to be breaking at the first occurrence of that newline character and not capturing the rest of the string.

Below is what I've managed to do so far. The first record always starts with `ABC-`, so I put that in my first capturing group and everything else after it, till the next occurrence of `ABC-` or end of file (if last record), should be captured by the second capturing group. The first row works as expected because there's no newline characters in it, but the rest won't.

My regex: `([A-Z1-9]+)-\d*,(.*)`

My test string:

```
ABC-1,01/01/1974,X1,Y1,Z1,"RANDOM SINLGE LINE TEXT 1",
ABC-2,01/01/1974,X2,Y2,Z2,"THIS IS
A RANDOM

MULTI LINE
TEXT 2",
ABC-3,01/01/1974,X3,Y3,Z3,"THIS IS

ANOTHER RANDOM
MULTI LINE TEXT",
```

Expected result is:

3 matches

**Match 1:**

Group 1: ABC-1,

Group 2: 01/01/1974,X1,Y1,Z1,"RANDOM SINLGE LINE TEXT 1",

**Match 2:**

Group 1: ABC-2,

Group 2: 01/01/1974,X2,Y2,Z2,"THIS IS

A RANDOM

MULTI LINE

TEXT 2",

**Match 3:**

Group 1: ABC-3,

Group 2: 01/01/1974,X3,Y3,Z3,"THIS IS

ANOTHER RANDOM

MULTI LINE TEXT",

[image]

Comment: Image is not helping. Provide input data in text format with your attempted regex and expected results.

Comment: You may try to rely on the first field pattern and use `(?m)^[A-Z]+-\d+,.*(?:\n(?![A-Z]+-\d+,).*)*`. See https://regex101.com/r/AsJi05/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thank you but that doesn't seem to be splitting my strings into capture group 1 and 2. It's selecting the whole thing as one group. I've updated my question with a bit more detail on the expected results.

Comment: So add the groups, what is so difficult here? `^([A-Z]+-\d+),(.*(?:\n(?![A-Z]+-\d+,).*)*)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, well actually, your regex works if I add my capturing groups: `^([A-Z]+-\d+),(.*(?:\n(?![A-Z]+-\d+,).*)*)`, so yeah that's what I was looking for!! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^([A-Z]+-\d+),(.*(?:\n(?![A-Z]+-\d+,).*)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AsJi05/2). Only use it with the *multiline* flag (if it is not Ruby, as `^` already matches line start positions in Ruby).

*Details*:

- `^`  - start of a line
- `([A-Z]+-\d+)` - Group 1: one or more uppercase ASCII letters and then `-` and one or more digits
- `,` - a comma
- `(.*(?:\n(?![A-Z]+-\d+,).*)*)` - Group 2:

  - `.*` - the rest of the line
  - `(?:\n(?![A-Z]+-\d+,).*)*` - zero or more lines that do not start with one or more uppercase ASCII letters and then `-` and one or more digits +  a comma

Answer (score 0):

You can try to limit the second group by a looking-ahead assertion:

```
(ABC-\d+,)(.*?(?=^ABC|\z))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oLt2uj/1) here.